# Как добавить условие с множеством значений в питоне?

Tags: python

```
fibonachi = int(input("Введите число от 0 до 250: "))
if fibonachi < 0:
    print("Это число меньше нуля")
elif fibonachi > 250:
    print("Это число больше 250")
if (fibonachi == 0 or 1 or 3 or 5 or 8 or 13 or 21 or 34 or 55 or 89 or 144 or 233):
    print("Это число Фибоначи!")
else:
    print("Это просто число")
```

Код достаточно простой, но
При вводе любого числа он выводит, что это число фибоначи
Как улучшить код, чтобы был вывод фибоначи при вводе любого из тех чисел?

Comment: if fibonachi in (0,1,3,... 233) ?

Comment: пожалуйста, запомните на будущее, что по-русски эти числа называются числами Фибоначчи (с заглавной буквы и с двумя "ч"), а латиницей - Fibonacci - с заглавной буквы и с двумя "c", без "h". Хотя, судя по вашему нику, с транскрипцией у вас не все ладно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше условие работает как

```
if (fibonachi == 0 or 
                  (1 or 3 or 5 or 8 or 13 or 21 or 34 or 55 or 89 or 144 or 233)):
```

где вторая часть всегда ненулевая

Для небольшого количества условий следует изменить так:

```
if (fibonachi == 0 or fibonachi == 1 or fibonachi == 3...
```

но в вашем случае это будет громоздко, и стоит проверять на вхождение в список, множество, или кортеж с помощью `in`, как уже в комментарии указали